# How are emotions and thoughts connected?

Tags: emotion

How are emotions and thoughts connected?

_Are certain emotions triggering certain types of thoughts?

_How is the link between emotions and thoughts materialized in the brain and the body?

Comment: Similar questions: [Why does a person feel sad without knowing the reason?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5334/7001), [Can the mind affect the physical brain? - a simple thought experiment](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8989/7001).

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Thank you, but I don't see how the second when relate to my question, and the first one, although the answers concerning emotions are thorough, doesn't make the link with thoughts

Comment: This short video explains the links between thoughts, emotions, and physiological responses very clearly. https://youtu.be/YUPIhzHa-68?t=458